# Python package to automatically create mathematical formula for a function

Tags: python, math, latex, jupyter, formula

I believe I learned of a Python package which can automatically convert a Python function into mathematical notation. For example, when applied to

```
def power(a, b):
  return a**b
```

the package would produce

power = a<sup>b</sup>

in a Jupyter Notebook, possibly using LaTeX.

Does anyone know what that package is?

Edit: I was thinking of a single-purpose package. I’m aware of SymPy and was not thinking of that, but the answer by @cards suggests it could work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected behaviour when parsing string with sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002903/unexpected-behaviour-when-parsing-string-with-sympy)

Comment: with `sympy`: `str` -- [`parse_expr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002903/unexpected-behaviour-when-parsing-string-with-sympy) --> `sympy.Exp` -- `sympy.latex` --> LaTeX:`str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on Mastodon reminded me of the package I was thinking of: [latexify](https://github.com/google/latexify_py).

> latexify is a Python package to compile a fragment of Python source
> code to a corresponding LaTeX expression

It can extract the mathematical operations from all lines of a function. Examples are in a [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MuiawKpVIZ12MWwyYuzZHmbKThdM5wNJ?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

A [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org) solution.

Idea: `python_func` --[sympy.parsing](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html)--> `Sympy.Expr` --[sympy.printing.latex](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#module-sympy.printing.latex) --> `LaTeX_str`

Used [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) to get the source code of the function.

Here an example trying to keep track also of the info provided in the comment by the author of the post.

Arguments **must** to be passed **only** in keyword form!

```
from inspect import getsource
from sympy import parse_expr, latex

def python2latex(func):
    # return a latex expression from a python function
    def __wrapper(**kwargs):
        # get expression in return
        *_, src_return = getsource(func).rstrip().rpartition('\n')
        *_, src_return = src_return.partition('return ')

        # cast to sympy expression
        expr = parse_expr(src_return, kwargs , evaluate=False)
        
        # not mandatory - compute final result without sympy
        result = func(**kwargs)

        # build a possible LaTeX expression
        template_result_TeX = "${} = {} = {}$"
        
        # apply the template
        return template_result_TeX.format(
            latex(parse_expr(src_return)),
            latex(expr),
            result)
            
    return __wrapper

@python2latex
def power(a, b):
    return a**b

result = power(a=3, b=4) # arguments as keywords!!
print(result)
```

Output

```
$a^{b} = 3^{4} = 81$
```

Comment: Thanks for working this out, @cards! Impressive how much can be extracted from a Python function. But I'm seeking a parametrized equation rather than one with values substituted in, e.g. instead of $3^{4} = 81$, I'd like $power = a^{b}$

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, in particular if there should be change on how to call the function (the way of the decorators are oo!:) So, try the following edit `result_TeX = f"${latex(parse_expr(src_return))} = {latex(expr)} = {result}$"` it returns `$a^{b} = 3^{4} = 81$` [of course you can modify at your own wish]

Answer (score 1):

The package you are referring to is likely SymPy, which is a Python library for symbolic mathematics. SymPy can be used to manipulate symbolic expressions and generate mathematical notation, including LaTeX output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm familiar with it because I've actually contributed documentation to it. SymPy would certainly be a way to create equations and output them in LaTeX, but that would require writing the equations in SymPy, for example defining symbols and equations.


What I recall learning of was a way to generate formatted mathematical expressions based simply on existing Python code. I believe it would be a decorator around a function such as `power` defined above, and would output the formatted mathematical expression in the Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @bwooster You might consider appending this clarification to your problem statement; it will help others to know that you already know about Sympy and you're looking for something else or something more.