# Define any mathematical function from user input

Tags: python, function, math, input, calculus

Im creating a python code that receives a mathematical function from user input and finds the roots of the specified function using Newton-Raphson method. The problem emerges when I try to use "def" funcion on a user input.
What I need is a specified function that I then can manipulate and take the derivate of and so on.
I've tried looking at other peoples similar problems but can't find any/don't understand the solution so please explain in simple terms.
Please note that I'm very new to programming.

This is what I tried to do:

```
from math import *

f = input("Write your equation: ") #e.g. 2x^2+log(x)
f = f.replace('^', '**') #I can't find a way to switch out multiplication with "*"

#My original thought was to do something like this, but even with '*' and '**', it still dosen't work
def f(x):
  return f
```

Earlier i got it to work for polynomials only using the folowing method:

```
  f = input("Enter the polynomial: ")
  f = f.replace('^', '**')            #replaces exponentiating
  f = f.replace('x', '*x')  #replaces multiplication with *, but dosen't work if x is alone
  f = f.replace('-*x', '-x')          # ̌
  f = f.replace('+*x', '+x')          # fixes the above issue
  if f.find("*") == 0:                # ^
      listf = list(f)
      listf.pop(0)
      f = "".join(listf)

  def g(x, f):
    f = f.replace('x', f"({str(x)})") #my solution to the original problem
    return eval(f)

  def g_prim(x):                      #defining the first derivative
    h = 0.00001
    return (g(x+h, f)-g(x, f))/h

  def g_biss(x):                      #defining the second derivative
    h = 0.00001
    return (g_prim(x+h)-g_prim(x))/h

  a = []                              #list of maximas

  for i in range(-50, 50, 5):         #finds the maxima and adds ± 0.5
    while abs(g_prim(i)) > 0.00001:
      i = i - g_prim(i)/g_biss(i)
    a.append(round(i+.5,3))
    a.append(round(i-.5,3))

  a = list(dict.fromkeys(a))
  b = []                              #list of roots

  for a in a:                         #Newton-Raphson from every maxima(±0.5)
    while abs(g(a, f)) > 0.00001:
      a = a - g(a, f)/g_prim(a)
    b.append(round(a,1))

  b = list(dict.fromkeys(b))
  print("The roots of the polynomial is:")
  print(b)
```

Comment: "What I need is a specified function that I then can manipulate and take the derivate of and so on". Python functions can only be called. You can take numerical derivatives with epsilon approximations, but not an analytical derivative. You may want to try using Pytorch though, it's a library that tracks the operations done on a "variable" that can later evaluate the value of the analytical derivative at specific points.

Comment: use `sympy`, here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424510/python-package-to-automatically-create-mathematical-formula-for-a-function/77425898#77425898) of usage. It has own string-parser and once you get a sympy-object you can derive, find roots, ... [all stuffs for symbolic manipulations]

Comment: Just a thought: "for a in a:" is this allowed in python?

Comment: @Fredy Yes, but not particularly recommended. Reminds me of this riddle: What does `(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)...(x-z)` simplify to?

Comment: @Stef I know the "riddle", ans its logic, and it's logical. But I think this is not the point. When you say "for a in a:" you assume something is both an element of a set, and the set. It's a mathematical nonsense. The good news is that we have now the complete program and I will try both things: the "for a in a:" and the OP's question. Have a nice day too!

Comment: "import math as *" is incorrect. Either use "import math as m" so "math.sqrt" will become 'm.sqrt", or (and I think it's better in your case) "from math import *"

Comment: For the rest, you already found the eval function, how it works, this is fine for arithmetics but for calculus, you should really consider cards' comment about "sympy".

Comment: @Fredy `for a in a:` is python, not math, and it's not nonsense. In python, variable names are assigned to objects, and this assignment can change over time. If you had something assigned to name `a`, and you write `for a in a:`, the elements of the object previously assigned to `a` are assigned to `a`, one after the other. There is nothing nonsensical about that, but it's very confusing and error-prone.

Comment: @Fredy In general if you want to study an algorithm mathematically (for instance to prove that it always terminates and correctly solves a problem), the usual thing to do is to make programming variables correspond not to mathematical variables, but to mathematical functions of time, because programming variables can change their values over time. Then `for a in a:` can translate mathematically to `a(0)` being an ordered set, `a(1)` the first element of this set, `a(2)` the second element of this set, etc, and although it's error-prone and confusing, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Fredy I always mix up the two (import math as * and from math import *), in the program I used the latter. I will look into using sympy, but I'm thinking about transitioning over to C, as it's usually faster.

Comment: @Biktor123 well I tried "import math as *" and got a splendid error (IDLE python 3). I understood you wanted to add math functions as log, sqrt, etc. in the user's entry string. In C also, I think you'll find libraries that allows calculus without rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: @Stef I figured what the "for a in a:" implied, there is an article in SO about that and the variation "for a[-1] in a: " very interesting. Thanks for clarifying in your 2 latest comments. I said "sense" because I am used to highly typed stuff and also maths. It wasn't a good word. In the 80ies, I remember using very odd lines of code, that wasn't very comprehensible at first read.